# Use revgeocode on two columns in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table df, where the data set looks like the following

```
   Pickup_longitude Pickup_latitude
1:          -73.945          40.799
2:          -73.930          40.864
3:          -73.944          40.696
4:          -74.001          40.688
5:          -73.926          40.755
6:          -73.936          40.812
```

I want to introduce a third column 'Pickup_Loc' which will be the text of the location. To obtain this I am using `revgeocode` from `ggmap` library.

I am not able to apply this fucntion on the column.

I tried this

```
df <- df[, pickup_loc := lapply(.SD,revgeocode),  .SDcols = c("Pickup_longitude","Pickup_latitude")]
```

But it gave me an error like this:

> Error: is.numeric(location) && length(location) == 2 is not TRUE

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Try assigning the frame and column on one side of the assignment and llapply on the other. Check my lapply grammar I could not run this to verify and I miss commas and closing braces often! `df$pickup_loc<- lapply(.SD,revgeocode),  .SDcols = c("Pickup_longitude","Pickup_latitude"))`

Comment: `lapply` will apply the function separately to each column. Presumably you need to apply both columns at once, maybe with `do.call`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ggmap::revgeocode` requires location in longitude/latitude format to be a numeric array of length 2. suggestion is to use `mapply` to concatenate the longitude and latitude into an array of length 2.

```
dt <- fread("
Pickup_longitude,Pickup_latitude
-73.945,40.799
-73.930,40.864
-73.944,40.696
-74.001,40.688
-73.926,40.755
-73.936,40.812
")

dt[, Address:=mapply(function(long, lat) ggmap::revgeocode(c(long, lat)), 
    Pickup_longitude, Pickup_latitude)]
```